# VMWare ESXi Server 3.5

Tags: vmware, esxi

I am trying to install VMWare ESXi 3.5 on a DELL GX280 machine which has SATA configurations. As ESXi doesn't support SATA, i am not able to proceed.

I could able to install on IDE (which is also not supported) by making some changes.
Is there a way to install on SATA as well??

Please let me know if anyone has tried it.

Thanks,
Shwetha

Answer (score 0):

This is a more appropriate question for the [VMware forums](http://communities.vmware.com/index.jspa) than here.

That said, ESXi supports SATA drives with no worries - I'm running a single SATA drive for boot with 4 additional SATA drives plugged into a Adaptec 2405 RAID controller for storage. Fully supported configuration.

Answer (score 0):

Newer versions ESX support a few SATA chipsets. At some point, the supported chipsets were:

- mptscsi_2xx (PCIE) ‐ LSI1078
- mptscsi_pcie ‐ LSI1068E (LSISAS3442E)
- mptscsi_pcix ‐ LSI1068 (SAS 5)
- aacraid_esx30 ‐ IBM serveraid 8k SAS controller
- cciss ‐ Smart Array P400/256 controller